# How long have Perl 5 formats been able to handle lexical variables?

Tags: perl, format

I seem to remember that Perl 5 formats only worked with package variables, and [PBP](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001735) seems to back that up on page 449:

> Formats rely on global variables for configuration, and on package variables for the data they are to format (see Chapter 5).

But a quick test seems to show otherwise (tested with 5.8.9, 5.10.0, and 5.12.1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $foo = "hello world";
write;

format STDOUT =
@<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
$foo
.
```

Did this change in some version of Perl 5, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: PBP seems to have gotten that wrong, at least from what you’ve posted here. I can’t recall whether I marked that on my rainbow-scribbled copy I gave back to Damian, and my clean copy is at home.

Comment: The `format` names that one loads the per-filehandle `$~` and `$^` variables with are package-visible ones.  You can’t just put `*WHATEVER{FORMAT}` into them; it stringifies, although I don’t know why.  Seems a logical extension.

Comment: Please don't take this comment as critical as it seems to be: aren't Perl formats, in large, deprecated?

Comment: @Axeman Yes, but when people ask about them I like to give correct information.

Comment: @Axeman: no, not deprecated in any way, shape, or form.  just an odd shaped hammer in search of increasingly rare nails.

Comment: *Exaudi orationem meam, Domine, et deprecationem meam.* No, Perl formats are by no mean “deprecated”. @ysth is right.

Comment: [Translation](http://translate.google.com/#auto|en|Exaudi%20orationem%20meam%2C%20Domine%2C%20et%20deprecationem%20meam.%0A) for those not familiar with Latin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since 5.001? From [`perlform`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlform):

> Lexical variables (declared with "my") are not visible within a format unless the format is declared within the scope of the lexical variable. (They weren't visible at all before version 5.001.)

Comment: A `format` works like a subroutine *declaration* but a `write` works like a subroutine *invocation*, wherefore you need statically scoped variables available to the former but dynamically scoped variables available to the latter.  Most of us prefer the former over the latter,  only resorting to the occasional `local` on system variables. For example, it makes no sense to have lexical `$/`, because `chomp` and `readline` couldn’t see it; that’s why it’s a dynamic.

Comment: Maybe the problem was that you couldn't declare a format inside a function back then (and therefore needed global variables).  I need to do more research.

Comment: Just because something isn’t inside a function doesn’t mean it has to use package variables.  There are file-scoped lexicals to be had.

Comment: @tchrist If a format could not be defined in a function (which it can at the moment) then it could not access the lexical variables defined in that function.  This would require the use of global or package variables to hold the data for the format.  Perhaps our definition of global variable differs.  To me a global variable is a lexical variable declared in the outermost scope or any package variable.

Comment: I use "package variable" completely interchangeably with "global variable".  A file-scoped lexical is not globally visible to the whole program.  So package variable == unlimited visibility variable == global variable.  lexical variable == scoped variable == nonglobal variable.

Comment: Variables granted access to via `our` are still package variables, as the `our` just creates a lexically scoped *alias* to a package=global variable. And `state` variables are just sticky `my` variables.

Comment: @tchrist I tend to use the term global variable to mean using a variable in a way that crosses scopes in an inappropriate way.  As far as I know there is no pithy term for this and the only problem with truly global variables is that they cross scopes in an inappropriate way, so it fits.  Of course, with [`PadWalker`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PadWalker/PadWalker.pm), even lexical variables can be truly global.

Comment: Luke Padwalker excepted, it isn’t possible to "cross" scopes, because names don’t leak. It is of course easy to have nested scopes. `{ my $count; sub init { $count = shift } sub dec { --$count } sub inc { ++$count } }`. I feel it is misleading to call `$count` a global.

Comment: @tchrist In that case `$count` is a shared state variable; you have explicitly created a scope for it. If you had said `my $count; sub init { $count = shift } sub dec { --$count }` then I would call `$count` a global variable. Claiming it isn't a global is equivalent to claiming that a variable declared in C outside of function that isn't declared `extern` isn't global because other libraries won't see it. That said, state variables suffer many of the same problems that plague global variables, but aren't quite so bad (because the contamination is limited to a smaller set of functions).

Comment: @tchirst By the way, the convention of putting (at)name isn't just for show, it causes the reply to show up in the "Most Recent Responses" section for that user.